# Silverlight: The resource {0} could not be resolved (in design time only)

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I've created a new silverlight 4 project in VS2010.

My App.xaml file is as follows:

```
<Application 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
            x:Class="ZCall.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ObjectResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>                        
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

a sample xaml view that generates the error is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ZCall.View.Control.CDetailsControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"  
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <toolkit:BusyIndicator x:Name="biCDetails" BusyContent="Busy...">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="170"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Name:" Style="{StaticResource PatientLabel}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtName" Style="{StaticResource PatientData}"/>
                </StackPanel>


            </Grid>
        </toolkit:BusyIndicator>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I get the errors on both PatientLabel and PatientData resources.

My style.xaml file is located in Resources folder in the root of the project.

My problem is that in design time, none of my styles defined in styles.xaml are recognized, and i get the error "The resource could not be resolved" for every style used, while in run time all the styles are resolved and displayed as it should be.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
kruvi

Answer (score 5):

Set Build Action of your App.xaml to ApplicationDefinition
the Error often occurs when you copy your App.xaml from one project to an other.

Answer (score 1):

i have tried many times some solutions, but i found now a working one. First create xaml file for holding the merged resource dictionaries, like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Assembly;component/Themes/PageStyles.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Assembly;component/Themes/CommonStyles.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Assembly;component/Themes/PageStyles.Dark.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Assembly;component/Themes/CommonStyles.Dark.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then declare it in you App.xaml to use the resource file:

```
<Application 
    x:Class="Assembly.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"       
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">

    <!--Application Resources-->
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/MainResource.xaml" />
    </Application.Resources>

    <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
        <shell:PhoneApplicationService 
            Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing" 
            Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
    </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>

</Application>
```

Now build your app and it would work in the designer and on the device or emulator.

Best regards

Enrico

Comment: Thanks Enrico, but I keep getting the exact same error in design time with your solution.

Comment: Hi, ok, that's bad. Do you set the file properties for "Build Action" to "Resource" or to another option? Here my settings: `Build Action:Page|CopyToOutput:Do not Copy|Custom Tool:MSBuild:Compile|CustomTool:[empty]`

Comment: file properties for Build action for all the files is exactly as you specified. :(

Comment: Creating a new solution and project files, and adding to the projects all the existing files solved this problem to me. just a work around, but it did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error with the added caveat that I was also using MVVM-Light. It turns out that the problems I was having stemmed from an [incorrect location of the Global View Model Locator](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/231763.aspx/1) definition in my **app.xaml** file.

This is how my **app.xaml** was configured. Notice the location of the Global View Model Locator within the **Application.Resources** tag. This is incorrect and caused me to have design time errors within Visual Studios.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles.xaml"/> 
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <!--Global View Model Locator-->
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
</Application.Resources>
```

The code below is correct. Notice that the Global View Model Locator is *inside* the **ResourceDictionary** tag. Once I moved the Global View Model Locator inside the **resourceDictionary** tag my design time errors went away.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />                
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!--Global View Model Locator-->
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
    </ResourceDictionary>        
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I am still learning and fairly new at Silverlight, so perhaps someone else can comment on why this fixed the problems I was having.

Comment: I tried your solution and now I am getting an error "domain operation cannot be started at design time". How can I get rid of that ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to the Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight assembly in your module projects. It provides the design-time magic to find resources defined in your shell project.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with the same problem in a WPF class library project. There is no App.xaml in this kind of projecst, so obviously the reason was somewhere else. And it was found that it is a broken VisualStudio project file: a `<SubType>Designer</SubType>` tag was missing in the  item representing the resource file:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
  <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

When the `<SubType>` was brought back, VS designer started working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I deleted initial App.xaml and added a manipulated App.xaml

Make sure that App.xaml Properties look like:

- Build Action: **ApplicationDefinition**
- Copy to Output Directory: **Do not copy**
- Custom Tool: MSBuild: **MSBuild:MarkupCompilePass1**
- Custom Tool Namespace: *[Blank]*
- File Name: *App.xaml*

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for loading resource dictionaries in design time without re-loading the same resource multiple times at runtime. I repeated the call of the needed ResourceDictionary in every UserControl that uses the included resources, and in the .xaml.cs of that UserControl, I added this line:

```
this.Resources=new ResourceDictionary();
```

to avoid inondating the application at runtime with the same resources. Of course you need to call the ResourceDictionary somewere else in the main project (App.xaml for instance).

Hope this works for your case too.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way the designer handles style definitions, any errors in a style file (eg app.xaml) will result in the designer not being able to resolve styling for any style that is defined in that file.

We had this problem that was caused by 2 minor errors in a style file. Once we fixed those errors and did a full rebuild on the entire solution all the styles were being resolved correctly throughout the entire solution.

So, go through the file that contains the resource and fix anything that the designer thinks is an error (blue squiggly line underneath) and then do a full rebuild.